# Redirect loop issue in my WordPress plugin - how can I fix it?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have created a WordPress plugin called "Password Protect Plugin" that enables users to password-protect the entire WordPress site and redirect them to a specific URL based on the entered password. However, I'm facing an issue where the plugin gets stuck in a redirect loop after the user enters the correct password and is redirected to the target page. The loop appears to be caused by the plugin repeatedly redirecting the user to the target page while being on the target page.

I have tried several modifications to the code, including changing the redirect logic, adding checks for cookies and caching, and using different hooks, but the issue persists.

Can anyone help me identify what's causing the redirect loop and provide guidance on how to fix it?

```
<?php

$passwords = array(
    'password-a' => 'https://example.com/a',
    'password-b' => 'https://example.com/b',
);

function password_protect_init() {
    global $passwords;

    if (is_admin() || is_user_logged_in()) {
        // If the user is logged in to the WordPress dashboard or logged in as a user, don't redirect
        return;
    }

    $current_url = (is_ssl() ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if (isset($_POST['my_website_password'])) {
        $password = $_POST['my_website_password'];
        if (array_key_exists($password, $passwords)) {
            setcookie('my_website_password', $password, time() + 86400, '/');
            wp_safe_redirect($passwords[$password]);
            exit;
        }
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE['my_website_password']) && array_key_exists($_COOKIE['my_website_password'], $passwords)) {
        $redirect_url = $passwords[$_COOKIE['my_website_password']];

        if ($redirect_url != $current_url && !is_page('password-protect')) {
            wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
            exit;
        }
    } elseif (!is_page('password-protect')) {
        wp_safe_redirect(site_url('password-protect'));
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'password_protect_init', 10);

function password_protect_template_redirect() {
    if (is_page('password-protect')) {
        // If the user is on the password form page, display the form
        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Password Protected</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post">
                <label for="my_website_password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="my_website_password" name="my_website_password">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'password_protect_template_redirect');

function password_protect_login_redirect($redirect_to) {
    if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to']) || $_GET['redirect_to'] == 'wp-admin/') {
        $redirect_to = site_url('password-protect');
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'password_protect_login_redirect');
```

Thanks in advance :).

Regards,
Noel

Comment: It might be helpful for debugging purposes to put something else into the URL, like in the QS, to determine which redirect happens where.

Comment: after the redirect from /password-protect?debug=1 happened to target page for example /a?debug=1 it just always redirects to /a?debug=1 again staying in this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue, if anyone interested in the solution :):

(Changed the hook from 'wp' to 'parse_request' for handling password protection. Separated form submission handling from the password protection function. Added a function to prevent canonical redirects on the password-protect page.)

```
<?php
    
    $passwords = array(
        'de' => 'https://lorenzgiordano.ch/de',
        'se' => 'https://lorenzgiordano.ch/se',
    );
    
    function password_protect_parse_request($wp) {
        global $passwords;
    
        if (is_admin() || is_user_logged_in()) {
            // If the user is logged in to the WordPress dashboard or logged in as a user, don't redirect
            return;
        }
    
        $current_url = (is_ssl() ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $current_url_no_slash = rtrim($current_url, '/');
        $password_protect_page = site_url('password-protect');
    
        if (isset($_COOKIE['my_website_password']) && array_key_exists($_COOKIE['my_website_password'], $passwords)) {
            $redirect_url = $passwords[$_COOKIE['my_website_password']];
    
            if ($redirect_url != $current_url && $current_url != $password_protect_page && $redirect_url != $current_url_no_slash) {
                wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
                exit;
            }
        } elseif ($current_url != $password_protect_page) {
            wp_safe_redirect($password_protect_page);
            exit;
        }
    }
    add_action('parse_request', 'password_protect_parse_request', 10);
    
    function password_protect_handle_form_submission() {
        global $passwords;
    
        if (isset($_POST['my_website_password'])) {
            $password = $_POST['my_website_password'];
            if (array_key_exists($password, $passwords)) {
                setcookie('my_website_password', $password, time() + 86400, '/');
                wp_safe_redirect($passwords[$password]);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('init', 'password_protect_handle_form_submission', 9);
    
    function password_protect_template_redirect() {
        if (is_page('password-protect')) {
            // If the user is on the password form page, display the form
            ?>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Password Protected</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form method="post">
                    <label for="my_website_password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="my_website_password" name="my_website_password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
            <?php
            exit;
        }
    }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'password_protect_template_redirect');
    
    function password_protect_login_redirect($redirect_to) {
        if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to']) || $_GET['redirect_to'] == 'wp-admin/') {
            $redirect_to = site_url('password-protect');
        }
        return $redirect_to;
    }
    add_filter('login_redirect', 'password_protect_login_redirect');
    
    function password_protect_prevent_canonical_redirect() {
        if (is_page('password-protect')) {
            remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
        }
    }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'password_protect_prevent_canonical_redirect', 8);
```